# Is it safe to develop with ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

According to Android devs page on ViewPager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

> Note this class is currently under early design and development. The
>   API will likely change in later updates of the compatibility library,
>   requiring changes to the source code of apps when they are compiled
>   against the newer version.

With that said, is it safe to be developing apps using this "beta" API?

Comment: I filed an issue to get rid of this hopefully-obsolete paragraph: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55609

Comment: Oh, seems like you filed it already. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to use. Many apps are using it. Swiping between screens has even become standard design language for Android apps.